# Can't install laravel-elixir-webpack-official

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm, gulp, laravel-elixir

Today I just wanted to install all dev dependencies on Laravel 5.2 using package.json from Laravel 5.3 but proces stucks on installing laravel-elixir-webpack-official

Here's my npm-debug.log:

http://pastebin.com/iVx93YYs
(link cause it's really long output)

I am using Windows 10.

Comment: have you tried rm -rf node_modules and npm install?

Comment: nah. I just tested it on other machine (same system) and it's working. Meybe it's problem with my project. Don't know. I will try it later.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue. The install hangs for several minutes, but does eventually complete.